# ScriptManager not supporting telerik radslider

Tags: asp.net

ScriptManager not supporting telerik radslider.Is there any way to support Telerik Radslider using Asp:scriptManager?

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
  <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="radscriptmanager" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I can not use RadScriptManage ,Certain limitation in my project